# How to Get Active URL of the current document? Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a complete newbie to Google Apps Script.

I wanted to retrieve the URL of the current document and use it to share on Google Classroom.

I have been trying but I know what is wrong with my code. Any advice?

Here's my code for the HTML part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  
  <script> function onOpen() {
    var currentDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var currentDocURL = currentDoc.getURL();
    }
  </script>


  <body>
        
  <!--<g:sharetoclassroom url='<?=fileLink=>' size="32"></g:sharetoclassroom>-->
  <g:sharetoclassroom url= "" size="32"></g:sharetoclassroom>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();` runs on a google server not in a browser

Answer (score 1):

Try [templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#code.gs) and a [printing scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) like this:

`<?= DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getUrl() ?>`